# How to produce Matplotlib plot with x-axis out of order?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot some y-data with an x-axis that does not appear in numerical order:

For example:

```
y = [100, 99, 93, 88, 85, 43]
x = [0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
plot(x, y)
```

I'd like the x-axis to show up as 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, in that order, evenly spaced, with the appropriate y values above.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use the `x` 'values' as the xtick labels instead.  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
y = [100, 99, 93, 88, 85, 43]
xt = [0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
ax.plot(y)
ax.set_xticklabels(xt)
fig.savefig("out.png")
```

produces

[image: pic with changed xtick labels]

More generally, you could set the `x` coordinates to be whatever you wanted, and then set `xticks` and `xticklabels` appropriately.

Comment: tested this on matplotlib 3.1.3 and you also need `ax.set_xticks(xt)` after `ax.plot(y)` for it to work correctly